# Excluding files from coverage with intern, do I need a custom reporter?

Tags: report, code-coverage, intern

I have a large project I'm writing intern tests against, I'm able to generate 90%+ coverage for my own package however coverage is being reported much less than this because other packages (such as dojo, dijit etc) are also being included in the report total.

Is there an 'out of the box' intern way to exclude files from coverage reports?

Istanbul supports an 'exclude-pattern', is it simply a case of writing another custom intern reporter to configure excludes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `excludeInstrumentation` configuration property. It is a regular expression of paths to exclude. See https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed excludeInstrumentation but it's more than appreciated